# Python how to convert multiple columns into common OneHotEncoding style categorical columns without duplicating same column names

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

```
cat_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
cat_2 = ["C", "A", "E", "A"]
cat_3 = ["NaN","F","NaN","NaN"]
  
# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'image_1': cat_1, 'image_2': cat_2, 'image_3': cat_3} 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    
df
```

Above I have given the example data, when using ***"pd.get_dummies(df)"*** I get the same categorical data's name duplicated with various names. In other words when used pd.get_dummies(df) I get:

[image]

As seen value "A" is repeated for image_1 and image_2.

What I am aiming for commonize a single column for every unique value instead of extra columns for the same value

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can `stack` first, then aggregate:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

*NB. If you use real NaNs, they will be absent by default. Also, in case you have several values of a kind in a row and don't want to have numbers higher than 1, use `max` instead of `sum` as aggregation function.*

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  1  0
3  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `get_dummies`

```
df = df.mask(df=='NaN')
out = pd.get_dummies(df,prefix_sep='', prefix='').groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
Out[25]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  1  0
3  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it using the OneHotEncoder Library. I need a consistent method since I will be using it for machine learning. The way the python classifies the data must be on the same order everytime. Thank you for your time!